# Going to gloox from Twisted. Getting access to full mesage node?

Tags: c++, xmpp, gloox

I'm making a Python application communicating through XMPP/jabber to a C++ app. On the Python end, I used Twisted. What I really like about Twisted is the ability to directly receive/send the "message" XML node and do whatever I want with it. (I.E using more stanza than just "body"). In order words, Twisted returns me an "Element" object and the send method accepts an "Element" object.

From what I've seen with gloox right now, the API is directly returning me the "body" string.

So, my simple question, is there an easy way to get access to the full message node using gloox?

Comment: I don't know Gloox, but the API doc for the Message class at http://camaya.net/api/gloox-1.0/classgloox_1_1Message.html certainly implies that you get a lot more than just the body string. Perhaps it would help to provide some code, or be more specific about what part of incoming messages you want to see.